# Thread.BeginThreadAffinity

Tags: c#, .net

I've been trying to squeeze a little more performance out of one of my program's, and was reading up on the priority and affinity settings, I came across `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity`, the documentation for it says:

> Notifies a host that managed code is about to execute instructions
>   that depend on the identity of the current physical operating system
>   thread.

I tested this out in my program and got about 3-4% increased performance. From what I understand, if your code is moved to a different physical operating system thread it loses the affinity setting, but with `Thread.BeginAffinity` it stays on the same thread, keeping the affinity setting, since mine is elevated, I get increased performance.

Is this how it works, or am I misunderstanding `Thread.BeginAffinity`?

Comment: A perf difference of 4% is not statistically meaningful.

Comment: I'll take what I can get, I seem to be consistently getting higher CPU usage with it when the thread affinity has been increased. Your comment doesn't help me at all either.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Context switching does cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) you are correct

> Some hosts of the common language runtime, such as Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2005, provide their own thread management. A host that provides
>   its own thread management can move an executing task from one physical
>   operating system thread to another at any time. Most tasks are not
>   affected by this switching. However, some tasks have thread affinity -
>   that is, they depend on the identity of a physical operating system
>   thread. These tasks must inform the host when they execute code that
>   should not be switched.
>
> For example, if your application calls a system API to acquire an
>   operating system lock that has thread affinity, such as a Win32
>   CRITICAL_SECTION, you must call BeginThreadAffinity before acquiring
>   the lock, and EndThreadAffinity after releasing the lock.
>
> Using this method in code that runs under SQL Server 2005 requires the
>   code to be run at the highest host protection level.